# Not able to delete AD user in window 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory

I am running on window 2008 R2 OS with AD installed on it. I have created few users. Now, i am trying to delete 2-3 users but it tells me that I either have insufficient rights or the account is protected against accidental deletion.
I have also tried to login with domain admin user but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> it tells me that [...] the account is protected against accidental deletion.

If the DC tells you that the object is protected against accidental deletion, then that's probably the case:

[image]

Remove that checkmark and you'll be able to delete the object

Comment: I have been logged in with domain admin user. I have clicked on properties of user but  the option "Protect object from accidental deletion" is disabled. I am not able to enable it.

Comment: Are you sure you're a domain admin?

Comment: Yes, I am damn sure. I have removed few users but not receive the same error in 2-3.

Comment: Hey got it. There was a advance feature option under view tab. As i have clicked their. The protect object from accidental deletion enable. I have checkmark their and now i am able to remove my AD user.